# Adding a list-column to a tibble in which each element is the first element of another list-column

Tags: r, purrr, tibble

I know how to do something analogousfor non-list-columns. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% mutate(first_cyl = first(cyl))
```

I expected that for list-columns, this will work:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest(.key = "x") %>% 
  mutate(first_x = first(x))
```

but produces an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was missing the list function. Now, this works:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest(.key = "x") %>% 
  mutate(first_x = list(first(x)))
```